# InnoDB table diskspace consuming all HDD space

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, mariadb

### **Background**

I have a MariaDB server installed, some of the tables use MyISAM and some of them use InnoDB. InnoDB is good for reducing query time because it is multi-core. I changed some of our huge tables into InnoDB.

Then I found my HDD is using more and more space. I have checked my CentOS 7 Linux and I found that ibdata1 is consuming my HDD space. And I know if I need to shrink the space I need to fully dump my MySQL server into a .sql file then  drop all databases. After that, stop the MySQL server and delete the ibdata1 file. Moreover, set `innodb_file_per_table` into `my.cnf`. Finally, import the sql back into the server.

Everything going well until I found this issue.

### **Issue**

I real-time checking my new HDD usage and I realised the table is now using a .ibd file with the name as same as the table name. And it is HUGE! After finishing the import, the HDD usage is even worse than before. I have tried to `OPTIMIZE TABLE` for a 750MB file to see if it can shrink the size but no luck. I also have a 14.8GB InnoDB table but I don't have another 14.8GB for MySQL to optimize my table and I don't think it can reduce the usage.

### **Attachment**

**Current my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
local-infile            = 0
max_connections         = 32768
long_query_time         = 5
query_cache_type        = ON
query_cache_size        = 200M
tmp_table_size          = 2M
max_heap_table_size     = 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
table_open_cache        = 4096
thread_concurrency      = 28
sort_buffer_size        = 16M
read_buffer_size        = 16M
join_buffer_size        = 16M

innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method     = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size    = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_read_io_threads  = 7
innodb_write_io_threads = 7
```

What can I do now?

Comment: Why the `sql-server` tag if the question is `mysql` specific?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  The disk space used by an InnoDB table (and indexes) is roughly 2x-3x what it would take with MyISAM.  This is something to live with.

Long answer:

If you did not have a bunch of spare disk space to start with, your conversion to InnoDB will eventually run out of space, regardless of file_per_table, etc.

- `innodb_file_per_table = OFF`:  All data and indexes for all *subsequently* `CREATEd` or `ALTERed` tables goes into the file `ibdata1`.  That file only grows; it cannot shrink.
- `innodb_file_per_table = ON`:  All data and indexes for all *subsequently* `CREATEd` or `ALTERed` tables goes into `.ibd` files -- each with the name of the table.  Generally, this is the better approach because it allows for better maintenance in the long run.

Either way, a similar amount of disk space will be taken.

Other issues:

- `query_cache_size = 200M` hurts performance; do not go above about 50M.
- Both InnoDB and MyISAM are capable of using multiple CPUs -- but only one CPU per *connection*.  On the other hand, MyISAM does "table locking", so there is less concurrency.  (This may have confused you into thinking it was a CPU issue.)
- Some `ALTERs` and all `OPTIMIZEs` copy the table over.  So, during the operation, you need enough disk space for an extra copy of the table.  When using `ibdata1`, this will expand, *but not contract*, the size of that file.  With `.ibd`, the space is given back to the OS.
- `ALTER` and `OPTIMIZE` may or may not shrink the size of the table and index(es) (and increase `Data_free`).  `OPTIMIZE` is almost never useful for InnoDB.
- Other [*tips on converting to InnoDB*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/) .
- I tend to like putting 'tiny' tables into `ibdata1` instead of `file_per_table`.  But it is a hassle--I have to think-ahead.